# Socket error "IP address not valid in its context" - Python

Tags: python, windows, django, networking, windows-server-2008

I'm using **Python 2.6** and **Windows Server 2008**.

The server has **two IP addresses 1 internal, 1 external**.

---

**I need Python to use the external IP address, but while doing so I get this:**

> socket.error: [Error 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

---

To be more precise I'm using Django's runserver command for who is familiar with it

---

#### Edit:

`ipconfig` only brings up the internal IP address, while all services I have running are using the external IP without any problems!

---

Any ideas?

Comment: That's an error Windows gives when you're trying to bind to address on the local machine that's not assigned to any of the adapters on the machine. If `ipconfig` doesn't show it, you can't bind to it. Maybe you want to bind to any address that's on the machine right now? (If the external address is NAT'ed to your internal one, binding to the internal one will be enough.)

Comment: @Rosh: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's an error Windows gives when you're trying to bind to an address on the local machine that's not assigned to any of the adapters on the machine. If `ipconfig` doesn't show it, you can't bind to it.

If the external address is on a router that is NAT'ing requests from it to the server's internal address, you can't bind to it because it's on a different machine. This is probably the case. You might want to bind to `socket.INADDR_ANY` (or its Django equivalent). This will bind to all addresses that are on the machine right now.

Also note that if the external address is NAT'ed to your internal one, binding to the internal one should be enough.

Comment: That error is also given when you try to Connect, SendTo, JoinLeaf when the remote address+port has something wrong with it (like port==0).  SendTo might return this error if you send to a multicast address when the socket isn't set for that via SetSocketOptions.  Windows uses this error for too many conditions, IMHO.