# Connecting to myself through my public IP through TCP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to connect to my own machine using my public IP. If I use `127.0.0.1` the connection is successful, but using the public IP results in the following error: `"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"`.

According to MSDN, the error might appear because no server application is running; however, I did run the 'server.py' script first, before running 'client.py. What should I do to fix this?

**server.py**

```
from socket import *
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
sock.listen(10)
conn, _ = sock.accept()
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import *
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((MY_PUBLIC_IP, 8888))
```

Comment: In server.py: you have to bind the socket to your public IP - or is that a typo?

Comment: By default mysql new installations are only allowed to connect from localhost. Check if this is your problem and change the configuration to allow remote connections.

Comment: @djf Trying to do that gives "OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context".

Comment: `[WinError 10049]` is a completely different error. It indicates that `MY_PUBLIC_IP` is not an IP on that machine. Make sure it's correct. Your problem is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657347/socket-error-ip-address-not-valid-in-its-context-python

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely your firewall or router if you have on. Try configuring your firewall to allow access on that port, and doing port forwarding if you're using a router.

Answer (score 0):

The server is listening on the loopback address only.
Try this instead:

```
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8888))
```