# trying to bind to specific external ip:: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context could not open socket-(python 2.7)

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a [Moxa device](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5150.htm) that create Tcp-ip message from serial data and send them to me by LAN.
i need to listen to hes specific external-ip(172.16.0.77) with python server.
ill try to do this:

```
    BUFFER_SIZE = 10000  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
    HOST = self.TCP_IP  #(172.16.0.77)
    PORT = self.TCP_PORT              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    s = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print msg
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.bind(sa)
            s.listen(1)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print msg
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print 'could not open socket'
    while s:
        print s.getsockname()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connection address:', addr
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if data:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("SamplesRecive"),data)
        conn.close()
```

and i get : [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context could not open socket
I need to divide the serves to many Moxa devices so i cant use `socket.INADDR_ANY`

Any ideas?

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: [tag:pss] on [ s.bind(sa)] ,Thank

Comment: The answer provided by `dsgdfg` below should solve the issue. Else here is a same post that might help you to find the reason. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4657548/2382792

Answer (score 1):

`socket.INADDR_ANY` equal to `socket.bind('0.0.0.0')`

if bind to "0.0.0.0" can listen all interfaces(which avaible)

Example of Moxa TCP :

```
import socket,time
import thread

#Example client
class _client :
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = False
    def run(self,clientsock,addr):
        while 1 :
            try:
                data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
                if data :
                    #do something with data
                    time.sleep(.1)
                    if self.status == False:
                        clientsock.close()
                        break
                    clientsock.send(next_query)


             except Exception,e :
                print e
                break
client = _client()
ADDR = ("0.0.0.0", 45500) #so you need port how to decode raw socket data ?
serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, 1)#gain 50ms tcp delay
serversock.bind(ADDR)
serversock.listen(10)

While True :
    clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
    if addr[0] == device_1_IP:
        client.status = True
        #start device1 thread(moxa is TCP client mode)
        thread.start_new_thread(client.run, (clientsock, addr))
        #if client.status = False you will be close connection.
```

**But my offer is "use moxa with TCP server mode"**

i am used 4x5450i 3x5250 over 120 device without any error.

Comment: [tag:dsgdfg] so i sock connect with a client and keep the connection and wait for receive?{while 1: received = sock.recv(10000)}

Comment: [tag:dsgdfg] so ,you create server then you connect hem with client that try to receive from the moxa tcp message (you dont use the addr param that yo pass in _client::run)?.. THANK !