# I am making a socket connection, but I am getting an Error

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.4

I am making a socket connection and when I try and connect to a different computer it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\stuff\server.py", line 9, in <"module"><br>  ##without the quotations the word would not appear because of the "<>" in html code.<br>
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))<br>
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Here is the code for the server/receiver:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = "192.168.1.157"
PORT = 5454

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:

    connection,client = s.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            print(bytes.decode(connection.recv(999)))
    except:
        connection.close()
```

And here is the code for the client/sender:

```
import socket

HOST = input("Connect to: ")
PORT = 5454

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    text = str.encode(input("Send: "))
    s.sendall(text)
```

It all works if I use 'localhost' for `HOST` in both server and client but the idea is that the receiver on someone's computer will connect to my PC and I have to input the IP of their PC for the sender.

Is it something I am doing wrong or something I missed? I am sorta new to this but I have looked at lots of tutorials and to me, this should work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the error when the client tries to connect to the listening server?

Comment: No, the server gets an error when trying to connect to the client.

Comment: Hmm normally the client would connect to the listening server, by looks of it your having a problem binding to the address you are specifying on server side. Do you fire up the server and it listens on the given port?

Comment: It is supposed to listen on the given port but gets an error before it does anything else.

Comment: [*The requested address is not valid in its context*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657347/socket-error-ip-address-not-valid-in-its-context-python) is e.g. raised during `bind()` by the Windows socket API when the address you are trying to use is not an address of a local interface. Is `192.168.1.157` the address of the server? You can check with `ipconfig` (might need `ipconfig /all`).

Comment: Yeah double check your address, I expect its as simple as not having the correct one.

Comment: I am not trying to connect to my laptop, i am trying to connect to my dad's laptop. I also checked though, his IP is definitely 192.168.1.157.

Comment: @Ruarri What happens when you replace the explicit IP with `s.bind('0.0.0.0', 5454)`? This tells the socket to listen to *all* local addresses.